# Generation of a set to be used in for_each

Tags: foreach, terraform

Is there a way to generate a `set` from an Integer? It would convenient if we have a `number_of_instances` parameter that is converted to set to be used in `for_each` Meta-Argument. In result, we don't need to write:

```
for_each = toset(["one", "two", "three",])
```

In stead, we just set a parameter:

```
number_of_instances = 3
```

For now I came up with this:

```
variable "number_of_instances" {
  type = number
  default = 0
}

locals {
  i = [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
    "f",
    "g",
    "h",
    "i",
    "j",
  ]
}

resource "null_resource" "main" {
  for_each = toset(slice(local.i, 0, var.number_of_instances))
  connection {
    name = each.key
  }
}
```

Comment: so you want to convert, 1,2,3 into "one", "two" and "three"?

Comment: no, I want to convert 3 into"one", "two" and "three"

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Where and how do you want to use that? There is no build in converstion of numbers to strings in words in TF.

Comment: I think I might hardcode a list of predefined values to be used by slice()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you could the following:

```
variable "number_of_instances" {
  default = 3
}

locals {
  numbers = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
  number_set = slice(local.numbers, 0, var.number_of_instances)
}
```

and then use:

```
for_each = toset(local.number_set)
```

Off course `numbers` must be pre-populated first.

Comment: Haha! I just implemented the same!